# Powershell JiraPS - Download Attachment with Get-JiraIssueAttachmentFile only returns true but no file

Tags: powershell, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm currently trying to download an attachment from Jira Server using the Powershell cmdlet JiraPS.

It works fine to authenticate and establish the session.
Also it works to get the attachment information using the function "Get-JiraIssueAttachment".

But then when I try to download the actual file using "Get-JiraIssueAttachmentFile" I just get "True" as output, but the file isn't being downloaded.

In the other direction it work. I am able to upload an attachment.
And I'm also able to download the attachment in the webinterface.

So at the moment I have no idea how to continue with this:

My current code is:

```
$JiraUrl = "http://jira:8080"
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = "***" 
$global:response

$secure_pwd = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$JiraCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $secure_pwd
$null = Set-JiraConfigServer -Server $JiraUrl
$null = New-JiraSession -Credential $JiraCredentials -ErrorVariable errorVar

$JAttach = Get-JiraIssue PRJ-351 | Get-JiraIssueAttachment -FileName "FiddlerSetup.exe"

Get-JiraIssueAttachmentFile -Attachment $JAttach
```

Did anybody manage to get this running?
Any tipp would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://atlassianps.org/docs/JiraPS/commands/Get-JiraIssueAttachmentFile/) Get-JiraIssueAttachment returns a boolean value rather than the file itself.  If you don't pass a -path parameter it downloads to the current working directory.  You can use Get-ChildItem to assign the file to your variable.

```
$JiraUrl = "http://jira:8080"
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = "***" 
$global:response

$secure_pwd = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$JiraCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $secure_pwd
$null = Set-JiraConfigServer -Server $JiraUrl
$null = New-JiraSession -Credential $JiraCredentials -ErrorVariable errorVar

Get-JiraIssue PRJ-351 | Get-JiraIssueAttachment -FileName "FiddlerSetup.exe"
$Jattach = Get-ChildItem FiddlerSetup.exe
   
Get-JiraIssueAttachmentFile -Attachment $JAttach
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the feedback.
In the meantime I did some more research.

For some reason we got an old version (2.9) from powershellgallery.

The current version is 2.14, which I downloaded from the github repository (https://github.com/AtlassianPS/JiraPS/tree/v2.14)

With this version it is working fine.